# Loops through Access column and find duplicates

Tags: sql, loops, ms-access, vba

I have a form in MS Access for adding new records and I am trying to create VBA code which to be triggered After Update of the Form. What I am trying to do is to loop through a column in a table linked to the Form and to check if the added value is in the column already, if yes update another column called"duplicate" for all duplicate records to "yes".

For example if the user add "Mike Down" and there is already a record with this name in the table, column "duplicate" for all records with this name to be updated to "yes".
I am totally new to VBA access and so far I only found how to do the loop:

```
Dim dbsMyDB As DAO.Database
Dim rstMyTable As DAO.Recordset
Dim frmForm As Form
intI = 1
With rstMyDB
    Do Until .EOF
    Loop
        If rstMyTable.Name = frmForm.Name Then
        .Edit
        --update column duplicate to "yes" for all duplicates
        .Update
        .MoveNext
        intI = intI + 1
End With
```

Comment: Why would you need a "duplicate" column? It's fairly trivial to just query for duplicates and it doesn't require you to manually enforce data integrity.

Comment: Are you trying to avoid having duplicates, or just mark them as duplicate?  Would the first record be considered a duplicate after the second record is added?

Comment: All of the records have unique primary key of type int and a duplicate record is not possible. I am trying to mark only all duplicate names, not trying to avoid them and yes the first record will be considered a duplicate also. This check can be performed also for a phone number or mail address, but at first I want to see if it is possible at all. We are trying to see if a person has applied for a second time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the *RecordsetClone*:

```
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

Set rst = Me.RecordsetClone

With rst
    Do Until .EOF
        If !Name.Value = Me!Name.Value Then
            If !ID.Value <> Me!ID.Value Then
                .Edit
                    !Duplicate.Value = True
                .Update
            End If
        End If
        .MoveNext
    Loop
End With

Set rst = Nothing
```

Comment: It works but is it possible the record that just has been added to be marked as duplicate also? The way it works now is when a record with the same name is added only the first one will be marked as duplicate and not the second one.

Comment: Works fine, but do you know why its triggered only when the form is closed? If 10 names are entered one after another and among them there are duplicates the code is not triggered.

Comment: Call the code in the _AfterUpdate_ event of the form.